# How to create a Fernet encryption algorithm in Dart

Tags: dart, encryption

I need help to create a Fernet encryption function in dart this is the code that I made:

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt_package;


String encryptFernet(String text) {
  final encrypt_package.Key key = encrypt_package.Key.fromUtf8('c1563NcXz90uGYpMqpfm_k10rOLVF5Q37AY6D016n_4=');
  final encrypt_package.Fernet fernet = encrypt_package.Fernet(key);

  final encrypt_package.Encrypter encrypter = encrypt_package.Encrypter(fernet);

  final encrypt_package.Encrypted encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(text);
  return encrypted.base64;
}
```

I would like this code to match this python code:

```
def encrypt_fernet(text):
    key_fernet = b'c1563NcXz90uGYpMqpfm_k10rOLVF5Q37AY6D016n_4='
    fernet = Fernet(key_fernet)
    encrypted = fernet.encrypt(text.encode())
    return encrypted
```

however I get this error `Exception has occurred. StateError (Bad state: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes.)`

Comment: What the error message already points out, the Base64url decoding is missing, try `key = encrypt_package.Key.fromBase64('c1563NcXz90uGYpMqpfm_k10rOLVF5Q37AY6D016n_4=')` (which apparently can decode not only standard Base64, but also Base64url data). Works on my machine.

Comment: It might seem simple but I think it's worth an answer, @Topaco.

Answer (score 0):

A [Fernet key](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#key-format) is a 32 bytes key that is Base64url encoded (according to [RFC 4648 sec. 5](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648#section-5)). The error message: *Bad state: Fernet key must be 32 url-safe base64-encoded bytes* points this out as well. The sample key you posted corresponds to this specification.

A Base64url encoded key has to be imported with [`Key.fromBase64()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Key/Key.fromBase64.html) (the method [`Key.fromUtf8()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/encrypt/latest/encrypt/Key/Key.fromUtf8.html) used by you performs a UTF-8 encoding, which is wrong in this context). Note that `Key.fromBase64()` supports both Base64 and Base64url, and mandatorily requires a paddig (with `=`) in both cases.

Another minor issue is that your code generates a Base64 encoded token, but Fernet specifies Base64url as encoding for the [token](https://github.com/fernet/spec/blob/master/Spec.md#token-format) as well. A Base64url encoded token (with padding) can be generated from a Base64 encoded token (with padding) by simply replacing `+` with `-` and `/` with `_` (s. [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table)).

Full code:

```dart
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' as encrypt_package;

...

String encryptFernet(String text) {
  final encrypt_package.Key key = encrypt_package.Key.fromBase64('c1563NcXz90uGYpMqpfm_k10rOLVF5Q37AY6D016n_4=');   // import Fernet key (32 bytes, Base64url encoded)
  final encrypt_package.Fernet fernet = encrypt_package.Fernet(key);
  final encrypt_package.Encrypter encrypter = encrypt_package.Encrypter(fernet);
  final encrypt_package.Encrypted encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(text);
  return encrypted.base64.replaceAll("+","-").replaceAll("/", "_");                                                 // Base64url encode
}
```